# How to view the Friends in google plus using java-google api?

Tags: java, google-plus

I am developing an application to view the Google plus friendlist of a particular user. So far i have completed the auth process.

**My Java code**

```
 package hello;

 import java.io.IOException;

 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

 import org.springframework.social.oauth2.GrantType;
 import org.springframework.social.oauth2.OAuth2Parameters;

 import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
  import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
 import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
 import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
 import com.googlecode.googleplus.GooglePlusFactory;

 /**
  * Servlet implementation class SignIn
 */
 @WebServlet("/SignIn")
 public class SignIn extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
 public SignIn() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  /**
   * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws   ServletException, IOException {
    GooglePlusFactory factory = new GooglePlusFactory("130186078654-sbrvrv50n3hmcd9man1id3r3ptn8e886.apps.googleusercontent.com", "tM857UHPp68G6a12fdduBiw-");
    OAuth2Parameters oAuthParams = new OAuth2Parameters();
    oAuthParams.setRedirectUri("http://google.com");
    oAuthParams.setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly");
    String url = factory.getOAuthOperations()
        .buildAuthenticateUrl(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE, oAuthParams);


    response.sendRedirect(url);
    //AccessGrant accessGrant = factory.getOAuthOperations().exchangeForAccess(code, oAuthParams.getRedirectUri(), null);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
   * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  }
```

How can i get the user friends after completing this oauth process?